# Golang struct gets different value from input

Tags: go

I am seeing weird behavior in the following code:

```
type A struct {
    D []int8
}

func main() {
    a := A{D: make([]int8, 0)}
    a.D = append(a.D, 0)

    b := a
    c := a
    b.D = append(b.D, 1)
    c.D = append(c.D, 2)
    fmt.Println(a.D, b.D, c.D)
}
```

I'm expecting output to be

```
[0] [0 1] [0 2]
```

However I got

```
[0] [0 2] [0 2]
```

Anyone know why...?

p.s. If I comment out line "a.D = append(a.D, 0)", or change the type of D from "[ ]int8" to "[ ]int", I got what I expected. Weird...

Comment: So many duplicates of this question. Read up about Go and pointers. I just answered a question similar to this a few hours ago. See this example https://play.golang.org/p/ZThHrP0pds and read my answer to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922965/i-cannot-modified-the-item-after-appending-to-array I'll track down a good duplicate to link this to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Go variables being overwritten (bug?)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277305/go-variables-being-overwritten-bug)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, changing the type doesn't fix it:  https://play.golang.org/p/fHX3JAtfNz

What is happening here has to do with the mechanics of append and reference types.

Basically, all three structs are pointing at the same underlying array, but each slice has its own unique length argument.

So when you append 1 to b, it is [0 1] with a length of 2.  c is still [0] with a length of 1.  You then append 2 to c, making it [0 2] with a length of 2.  Inadvertently, you are also changing the second value of the array in b.  If you could change the length of the a without append, it would also be [0 2].

Make sense?  Pointers and slices are weird.  Full story is here:  https://blog.golang.org/slices

Comment: Slices specifically are weird. Pointers in Go are amazing, but if you aren't aware that Go is pass-by-value, you can get tripped up.

Comment: Pedantic maybe, but calling anything in Go a "reference type" is misleading, and can lead to some misunderstandings of common Go behaviors. For reference: https://dave.cheney.net/2017/04/29/there-is-no-pass-by-reference-in-go

Comment: Eh, _types_ can be "reference types" in Go.  It's just that nothing is passed by reference.  Slices are inherently references, as are maps, channels, and a couple of other primitives.  When passed in, the variables themselves are still copies (ie. you get a new version of the slice header, and any changes to that slice header (like length or the address of the underlying array) do not propagate), but the underlying data referenced can still see this "pass-by-reference" type behavior.

Comment: The problem is, you can't just say "nothing is passed by reference in Go", because that's not mechanically true.  Sure, everything is _technically_ passed by value, but since reference types actually _do_ exist in Go (including a number of primitives), it's important to understand the actual mechanism.  We get a lot of questions out here about why the underlying data in a slice changes when another function alters it by index or appends over it or something.